# Problems launching a virtual machine using the android avd manager

Tags: android, eclipse, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems launching Android java project in a Android Virtual Machine using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387793/problems-launching-android-java-project-in-a-android-virtual-machine-using-eclip)

I have installed and set up Eclipse and the plugin ADT in order to work with Android SDK. So far so good.
But when I try to launch a VM(virtual Machine) for any android platform that I choose (for example: android 3.2) I just get the skin launched together with a keyboard console and phone buttons, it seems to boot up to a state and then does nothing but displays the android logo on the main vm screen and that's all it does - no more!, no VM functionality!, what's going on? Have I missed out some step? Please help...

Have been waiting sometimes over 10 mins in each case for the emulator to start.

I launched/ran an Android project test sample; 'hello world' from the eclipse environment after installing the ADT plugin  for Android
These are the error messages I had displayed in the console ddms:

> [2012-04-30 14:31:20 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
>   [2012-04-30 14:31:20 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch! [2012-04-30
>   14:31:20 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally. [2012-04-30 14:31:20
>   - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity activity launch
>   [2012-04-30 14:31:20 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching
>   new emulator with compatible AVD
>   'leighs_basic_hardware_secound_virtual_device' [2012-04-30 14:31:20 -
>   HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device
>   'leighs_basic_hardware_secound_virtual_device' [2012-04-30 14:31:40 -
>   Emulator] Warning: No DNS servers found [2012-04-30 14:31:52 -
>   Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
>   [2012-04-30 14:31:52 - Emulator]  [2012-04-30 14:31:53 - HelloAndroid]
>   New emulator found: emulator-5554 [2012-04-30 14:31:53 - HelloAndroid]
>   Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
>   [2012-04-30 14:49:03 - HelloAndroid] HOME is up on device
>   'emulator-5554' [2012-04-30 14:49:03 - HelloAndroid] Uploading
>   HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554' [2012-04-30 14:49:03 -
>   HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk... [2012-04-30 14:51:38 -
>   HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device
>   'emulator-5554! [2012-04-30 14:51:38 - HelloAndroid] (null)
>   [2012-04-30 14:51:39 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!

At no point have I have anything but the Android logo displayed on my emulator. I have tried various platform emulators - none of them are performing!

A second lot of errors I received back on a test run  after I checked the user data wiped in the Run configuration  menu was: 
result

> : [2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 1455
>   [2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator] [2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator] This
>   application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
>   way. [2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator] Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information.

Bench mark results of my computer using Novabench incase anyone wants to check, are:

> 30/04/2012 17:45:59 Microsoft Windows 7 Starter Intel Atom N550
>   1.50GHz @ 1500 MHz Graphics Card: Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator 3150
>
> 1014 MB System RAM (Score: 78)
>   - RAM Speed: 1610 MB/s
>
> CPU Tests (Score: 70)
>   - Floating Point Operations/Second: 24110532
>   - Integer Operations/Second: 43813828
>   - MD5 Hashes Generated/Second: 159380
>
> Graphics Tests (Score: 1)
>   - 3D Frames Per Second: 3
>
> Hardware Tests (Score: 6)
>   - Primary Partition Capacity: 87 GB
>   - Drive Write Speed: 14 MB/s