# Problems launching Android java project in a Android Virtual Machine using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, virtual-machine

I have installed and set up Eclipse and the plugin ADT in order to work with Android SDK. So far so good. But when I try to launch a VM(virtual Machine) for any android platform that I choose (for example: android 3.2) I just get the skin launched together with a keyboard console and phone buttons, it seems to boot up to a state and then does nothing but displays the android logo on the main vm screen and that's all it does - no more!, no VM functionality!, what's going on? Have I missed out some step? Please help...

Have been waiting sometimes over 10 mins in each case for the emulator to start.

I launched/ran an Android project test sample; 'hello world' from the eclipse environment after installing the ADT plugin for Android These are the error messages I had displayed in the console ddms:

> [2012-04-30 14:31:20 - HelloAndroid]
>
> [2012-04-30 14:31:20 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
>
> [2012-04-30 14:31:20 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
>
> [2012-04-30 14:31:20
>   - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity activity launch
>
> [2012-04-30 14:31:20 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching
>   new emulator with compatible AVD
>   'leighs_basic_hardware_secound_virtual_device'
>
> [2012-04-30 14:31:20 -
>   HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device
>   'leighs_basic_hardware_secound_virtual_device'
>
> [2012-04-30 14:31:40 -
>   Emulator] Warning: No DNS servers found
>
> [2012-04-30 14:31:52 -
>   Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
>   [2012-04-30 14:31:52 - Emulator]
>
> [2012-04-30 14:31:53 - HelloAndroid]
>   New emulator found: emulator-5554
>
> [2012-04-30 14:31:53 - HelloAndroid]
>   Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
>
> [2012-04-30 14:49:03 - HelloAndroid] HOME is up on device
>   'emulator-5554' [2012-04-30 14:49:03 - HelloAndroid] Uploading
>   HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>
> [2012-04-30 14:49:03 -
>   HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
>
> [2012-04-30 14:51:38 -
>   HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device
>   'emulator-5554!
>
> [2012-04-30 14:51:38 - HelloAndroid] (null)
>   [2012-04-30 14:51:39 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!

At no point have I have anything but the Android logo displayed on my emulator. I have tried various platform emulators - none of them are performing!

A second lot of errors I received back on a test run after I checked the user data wiped in the Run configuration menu was: result

> : [2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 1455
>   [2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator]
>
> [2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator] This
>   application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
>   way. 
>   [2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator] Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information.

Bench mark results of my computer using Novabench incase anyone wants to check, are:

> 30/04/2012 17:45:59 Microsoft Windows 7 Starter Intel Atom N550
>   1.50GHz @ 1500 MHz Graphics Card: Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator 3150
>   1014 MB System RAM (Score: 78) - RAM Speed: 1610 MB/s
>   CPU Tests (Score: 70) - Floating Point Operations/Second: 24110532 -
>   Integer Operations/Second: 43813828 - MD5 Hashes Generated/Second:
>   159380
>   Graphics Tests (Score: 1) - 3D Frames Per Second: 3
>   Hardware Tests (Score: 6) - Primary Partition Capacity: 87 GB - Drive
>   Write Speed: 14 MB/s

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364767/problems-launching-a-virtual-machine-using-the-android-avd-manager Please do not post your questions multiple times.

Comment: Especially Honeycomb and ICS are very slow to start in a emulator. I haven't been able to start Honeycomb properly at all on my machine (reacts too slow to be workable). Try if you can start a 2.x version of Android in the emulator, they usually start more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you Run your project or only start an emulator? After starting emulator, click Run button and select "Run as Android project".

Comment: Hi, No, I did not run a project, perhaps I should do so, thanks I will try your suggestion. Although I am surprised but glade if you are right - I mean I was expecting the android home screen to be displayed!

Comment: If you run your project as an android project, emulator will start your project automatically. So if you see Android Home Screen, means that you did not run your project correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how long you waited, but starting the emulator the first time (before you have a snapshot) can take quite a long time. Depending on you hardware it can take more than 10 minutes to launch.

Comment: Yes it can take quite a while. One can try running adb logcat or using DDMS and get some sense that it's doing something (probably dexopting...).  Also there's a commandline switch to have the emulator show console output.

Comment: I waited about 10 mins it so. What is meant by the snap shot?  I don't recall having taken a snap shot using the camera!-Is that what you mean?

Comment: Would it be possible my computer is too slow?

Comment: A snapshot is when the virtual machine save it's entire state to a file. This is usually done after the boot sequence it completed successfully. When you later want to start your virtual machine again, using the snapshot, you do not really have to boot your VM from scratch but it basically just read the state from the snapshot. I guess it could be compared to hibernation mode on a regular PC (laptop), even though it's not the same.

Comment: Sorry, missed to answer on the "too slow" question. I am not sure, but I doubt it can be too slow. The [system requirement](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) does not say anything about the HW requirement as far as I can see. But if you have a slow CPU and little RAM it will be VERY slow.

Comment: Look like you run out of memory. If you try to run an ICS (ice cream sandwich (4.x)), by default the emulated device will have 1gb of ram. You might want to decrease that since your computer seem to have only 1gb. Or try a 2.3.3 emulator which default to 256meg ram. Ian more or less throwing out ideas now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue which was solved by creating a new emulator and running it. You can check progress in Devices view through DDMS. Sometimes, this problem may occur when a snapshot enabled emulator hangs because of error, which can be solved by starting the emulator with user data wiped.

Comment: Hi, I tried  what you said - wiping user data, and the result:[2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 1455
[2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator] 
[2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2012-04-30 17:20:27 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Emulator thread automatically cuts off if for some time you have not done any activity on it..
so.. keep running your app to keep emulator on LIVE!

My advice - if you having an android phone.. please usb debug it and Debug your application on your phone... You will feel relieved from the long durations of the emulator........ to run!! :)